# Display Hyperlink field on rows based on value from the database

Tags: vb.net, gridview, hyperlink, rowdatabound

How do I dynamically display the 'Edit' on the hyperlink field based on the values on the rows, generated from the database.

N/B.: the gridview automatically generates rows.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a `DataGridViewLinkColumn` in the grid with **Edit** displayed if appropriate? Like this:

[image]

In which case, make the whole column a LinkColumn and whether or not it's clickable will be taken care of internally by the grid. Columns which don't display **Edit** will not be clickable.

If you don't mean this then please provide more detail.

Comment: Exactly what am looking for but how do I make some rows in the Hyperlink Column blank based on values from a table, for example if a column value is 'Regular', Edit hyperlink won`t display but if it is 'super' then 'Edit' will show??

Comment: @user851971 you would have to say more about what kind of object your grid is bound to and what data connectors you're using to pull data from your database